# Thymeleaf, Ajax, Springboot

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to use ajax with Thymeleaf, however I have faced some problems and I haven't solve it yet.
My operation is try to send a parameter to controller than calculate it and display in same page into a label.
My HTML code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="Thing" value=""/>
<script th:inline="javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementsByName("Thing")[0].addEventListener('change', doThing);
        function doThing(evt) {
            var url = [[@{/
                calculation
            }
        ]]
            ;
            $("#fill").load(url + '?input=' + evt.target.value);
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="fill">

</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the html code, I use ajax and redirect it to controller with var url = [[@{/calculation} ]].
My controller.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/calculation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public int multiply(@RequestParam int input, Model model) {
    return input;
}
```

With these operation I can calculate input and send it to my html. Than with  ajax function, I capture it and send to    . After that, I see my success result on the page.
My problem is that, I want to send the input from controller to

```html
<div id="fill"><p th:text="${amount}"/></div>
```

And For it I need to change my controller of course like that.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/calculation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String multiply(@RequestParam int input, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("amount",input);
    return "test";
}
```

}

However, I couldn't write my input value to label with using of thmeleaf.
The problem is when I do first operation, there is no problem, but if i want to assing the input value to a label or an input text, my operation is not working.

Could you help me please.

Comment: I thought the solution given yesterday was about what you needed. What exactly didn't work and why do you want to use models + templates for your AJAX call? By doing this, you will send an entire HTML page as an AJAX response. While this is not necessarily a problem, it doesn't really make it clear to me. The advantage of AJAX is that you only have to send data through AJAX requests and that you neve have to reload your browser, so why exactly do you want to send an entire HTML page rather than data?

Comment: Hi, yes my problem was to return entire page, however if i return data, its solved. thanks a lot for your help.